# Can the Powder Tower be used while its owner is bewitched?

Tags: citadels

I played as `Witch` and bewitched `Thief`. The `Thief` has previously built the `Powder Tower` and would like to use it at the turn he's bewitched.

Can the `Thief` or the `Witch` use the `Powder Tower` this turn?

Answer (score 4):

No one can use the Powder Tower this turn.

The Thief can't use the Powder Tower, because he's bewitched he loses his turn after taking his action (choose 2 gold or 1 card).

As the Witch, when you bewitch another character you still play with your own city. Since the Powder Tower is not in your city, you can't use it.

A quote from the rules that best describes this:

> When the bewitched character is called upon, its player must show his character card, take an action, and then immediately end his turn. [...] You now resume this player’s turn as if you were playing the bewitched character,
>   using all the character’s powers in **your city**. You still build districts from your hand of cards and pay with your gold (including taxes).

Comment: What makes you saying that ? An official rule ?

Comment: Yes, this is all based on rules. I will add these rule citations.